# Jar execution failed on double click

Tags: java, jar, executable

I'm new to java and I tried to create a simple gui to test if the jar file will execute. I used netbeans to create the jar but there is a problem, if I double click the jar a cmd window pops up and then close very fast and then nothing happens.

However, if I use `java -jar my.jar` in cmd the gui runs as expected (It's a simple window with a textbox). I don't understand why this happens.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Does the jar have a manifest? Can you share it?

Comment: The onlly thing that the manifest.mf contains is this: Manifest-Version: 1.0
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build

Comment: Assuming your enviroment is Windows, Try java -version from prompt and see if your javaw association uses the same vm in registry: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jarfile\shell\open\command` should be something like "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*"